# jcr xpath search text with special characters ? ! +

Tags: xpath, lucene, jcr

I try to nodes with property that contains some text with special character like ? + and !

I have 4 nodes:

```
/tmp/exclamation[@prop="value with!"]
/tmp/plus[@prop="value with+"]
/tmp/question[@prop="value with?"]
/tmp/string[@prop="value with string"]
```

Now my queries:

```
/jcr:root/tmp//*[(jcr:contains(@prop, 'with') )]
```

return me all 4 nodes

```
/jcr:root/tmp//*[(jcr:contains(@prop, 'with\!') )]
```

return me all 4 nodes

```
/jcr:root/tmp//*[(jcr:contains(@prop, 'with\?') )]
```

return me all 4 nodes

```
/jcr:root/tmp//*[(jcr:contains(@prop, 'with\+') )]
```

return me all 4 nodes

How I should correctly escape ! + ? to get only node that mach my search criteria?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the characters you are trying to escape are legal XML characters and below are illegal ones:

> ```
> & - &amp;
> < - &lt;
> > - &gt;
> " - &quot;
> ' - &apos;
> ```

So no need to escpae those characters and just perform your XPath query with a normal contains clause:

```
/jcr:root/tmp//*[(jcr:contains(@prop, 'with!') )]

/jcr:root/tmp//*[(jcr:contains(@prop, 'with?') )]

/jcr:root/tmp//*[(jcr:contains(@prop, 'with+') )]
```

Comment: in JCR it it a little difrent than normal XPath 
first on cause error:
Exception building query: `org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'with!': Encountered "" at line 1, column 5. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "*" ... ... ... ... ... "[" ... "{" ... ... ... "*" ...`

second one doesn't find anything

and third return me all 4 nodes